# SAS Data Table Using PROC REPORT

Tags: stored-procedures, sas, tabular

I'm a beginner using SAS and I was tasked with creating a table that looks like the following:

```
                      Group A                           Group B          All
               A   B   C   D   E   F            G  H  I  J  K  L  M 
Age 
   n           
   mean(sd)
   median
   min-max 
Gender
   n 
   fl
   ml
Race
   n 
   white 
   asian
   hispanic 
   black
```

The blanks in the table are just the calculations based on the criteria. What I've considered doing is the following but it doesn't look right and there are errors. Is there anyway to fix this or use proc freq/ proc tabulate if it's easier:

```
Libname test '/home/user/username'; 
DATA test; 
SET test.test(keep = GROUP LETTER AGE GENDER RACE); 
RUN; 
PROC SORT DATA = test; 
    BY GROUP LETTER AGE GENDER RACE; 
PROC MEANS DATA = test; 
    CLASS GROUP LETTER;  
    VAR AGE GENDER RACE; 
RUN; 
PROC PRINT DATA = test; 
    TITLE 'Demographics';
RUN;
PROC PRINT DATA=test;
RUN;  
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA = test.test;
            OUT = test.test;
            BY GROUP LETTER;
            VAR GROUP LETTER;
RUN; 
PROC REPORT DATA = asl.asl;
    COLUMN GROUP LETTER AGE GENDER RACE; 
    DEFINE GROUP /DISPLAY 'Group'; 
    DEFINE LETTER /DISPLAY 'Letter';
    DEFINE AGE /DISPLAY 'Age'; 
    DEFINE GENDER /DISPLAY 'Gender';
    DEFINE RACE /DISPLAY 'Race';
RUN;
```

Comment: Bottom of the page you'll fin dthe link to a paper (and code) that illustrates how to do this. It's not as straightforward as it could be :( https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Studio/Demographic-table-creation/td-p/406722

Comment: Thanks so much Reeza. This is extremely helpful and I'm glad to see I'm not the only one scratching my head at this.